# Xcode asset catalogue `Alignment` properties are ignored for `imageWithName:`

Tags: uiimage, alignment, asset-catalog

The Xcode asset catalogue editor supports an `Alignment` property for images. It very much seems like this is intended as a mechanism for setting a `UIImage`'s `alignmentRectInsets`, and Apple's [Asset catalogue reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html) strongly suggests this too:

> alignment-insets
>
> Dictionary
>
> The insets for alignmentRectInsets in UIImage or for alignmentRect in NSImage. The inset tag can be omitted.

However, when I load images from a catalogue that I've set an `Alignment` on with the editor, it don't get an alignment.

I'm loading images using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`.

Is this a known bug, or is there some subtlety I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done some testing and I think I've found why it wasn't working.

## There's a (small) Bug

If you don't set *all* of the `alignment` values in the asset catalogue editor to something other than `0`, then *none* of the alignment values will be honoured when you load that image resource. As it is perfectly reasonable for some alignment values to be `0`, I believe this is a bug and I'll raise it on Radar. However – this said, the feature is still pretty useful and I plan to use it.

## Pixels & Points

It's worth knowing that the Alignment, that you set in the asset catalogue editor for a **multi-scale PNG**, is defined in **pixels** and **not in points**.

When you load the asset and then ask the image for its `alignmentRectInsets`, the result is reported **in points**. Ie, the scale factor of that particular asset will be applied to the values that you set in the editor.

An example: if you set an alignment of `30, 30, 30, 30` on your `@3x` asset, then load the `UIImage`, you'll see it's `alignmentRectInsets` are `10, 10, 10, 10`.

## Vector Assets

I also tested a vector asset. Here, you have one vector image, and you specify one set of alignment values for it.

In this case of a **single vector asset**, the Alignment in the asset catalogue editor is defined in **points** and **not in pixels**. This is the opposite situation to a multi-scale PNG!

When you load the asset and ask for its `aligmentRectInsets`, then you'll see the same values reported, regardless of scale the UIKit loads for that image.

… This actually makes sense, and wouldn't work if done differently. But it seems like it might catch people out.